# Running an initialization function once in a node application deployed in multiple instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I have a node application backed by rethinkDB which is deployed in 8 instances and the application contains an initialization function which performs certain operations needed for the application.

The issue is that when the node server starts up the initialization function run once in every single instance (i.e. the function runs 8 times 1 in each instance). This causes issues in different parts of the app. Is there a simple/elegant way to control the execution of the initialization function so that even though the node app runs in 8 instance this particular function run only once when the node server starts up via npm start.

Comment: There are many, many ways. This is venturing into the realm of service discovery and is a very broad question.

Comment: You could try a flag in your DB. On initialisation check for the flag and if it has been set then don't run the init function. This would cause problems if you are launching the instances simultaneously. You could also have one instance 'lock' the DB collection and not let the others update the DB if locked. There isn't really one solution it is dependent on your specific setup and what the initialisation is doing

Comment: Providing some code would help immensely :D

Comment: @CarlosSultana  - Yeah the instances are launched simultaneously. Locking the DB collection might work. Actually the initialization method performs simple manipulations on the DB fields via the node service. For code example we can consider a simple function as the initialization method which runs in parallel for 8 times because of the number of instances.